# Xml Schema for repeating sequence of elements

Tags: xml, xsd

I have xml as follows

```
<Search>
    <Term />
    <And />
    <Term />
    <And />
    <Term />
</Search>
```

There can be n number of Terms and n-1 Ands (n > 0) in the sequence as shown. I tried the following xml schema but above xml would not get validated against the schema. 
*Error: cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'Search' is not complete. One of '{And}' is expected.*

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="Search">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>               
                <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:element name="Term" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="And" type="xs:string" />
                </xs:sequence>              
                <xs:element name="Term" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="xs:string" />             
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Appreciate any help with the xml schema.

Comment: What is the purpose of the "And" element? Are you using it like an operator?

Comment: Yes, it is an operator. There are multiple types of operator such as or, not, and etc. But I am working on it using abstract types.

Comment: Your XSD is not valid. It violates the Unique Particle Attribution rule.

Comment: I see. Eclipse did not tell me XSD is not valid. I could combine <Term> and <And> as one complex element but that does not seem a good solution to me.

Comment: I presume the `Term` element will get some additional information.  Is the same true for the `And` element?  If not, why include the And element at all in the schema?  If it is implicit, then you don't need it.  If all terms that are present in the document will be And'ed together, then you don't need to explicitly state that in the xml file itself.

Comment: Yes, 'And' has additional information which can vary. Also there can 'Or' in place of 'And'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Reordering them like this seems to do it. Am I missing anything?

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="Search">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Term" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                  <xs:element name="And" type="xs:string" />
                  <xs:element name="Term" type="xs:string" />
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 4):

The revised form of the content model will indeed recognize the language described.

But your XML might be a bit more idiomatic, and would almost certainly be easier to process, if you thought of the XML in terms of the abstract syntax tree you want, rather than in terms of a literal transcription of a surface syntax designed for sequences of tokens rather than trees.

Instead of using an empty `And` element between terms, wrap the conjunction of terms in an `And` element.

```
<Search>
  <And>
    <Term>...</Term>
    <Term>...</Term>
    <Term>...</Term>
  </And>
</Search>
```

It's now trivially easy to do arbitrary Boolean combinations, without having to worry about what precedence order to ascribe to the operators:

```
<Search>
  <Or>
    <And>
      <Term>...</Term>
      <Or>
        <Term>...</Term>
        <Term>...</Term>
      </Or>
    </And>
    <And>
       <Term>...</Term>
       <not><Term>...</Term></not>
    </And>
  </Or>
</Search>
```