# Receiving an error when trying to validate XML Schema with a sequence of semi-ordered compulsary and optional elements

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-parsing

I'm having trouble validating XML against an XSD that has a nested sequence with optional elements. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11059363/xml-schema-for-repeating-sequence-of-elements) from 3 years ago is similar but unfortunately doesn't solve my problem. Take this example XML:

```
<root>
    <a>...</a>

    <b>...</b>
    <c>...</c>

    <b>...</b>  
    <c>...</c>
    <d>...</d>
    <d>...</d>

    <b>...</b>
    <c>...</c>
    <d>...</d>

    <END>...</END>
</root>
```

And my corresponding XSD:

```
<xs:schema ...>
    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>

                <xs:element name="a" type="aType"/>

                <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:element name="b" type="bType"/>
                    <xs:element name="c" type="cType"/>
                    <xs:element name="d" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="3" type="dType"/>
                </xs:sequence>

                <xs:element name="END" type="eType"/>

            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

In other words:

- "a" must occur once, followed by:
- a nested sequence consisting of "b", "c" and "d" in order. However, "d" is optional and can occur up to 3 times.
- finally, "END" must occur once.

The types are complexType's defined elsewhere in the schema.

The XSD represents logically what I want to do but isn't working. It appears to be valid XSD (the parser doesn't error out when reading the XSD). But I'm getting errors that lead me to believe I'm not structuring this correctly.

Here's my JavaScript/Java code to validate the XML against the XSD while constructing the DOM (using Rhino JavaScript engine so this will look weird):

```
var schemaReader = Packages.java.io.StringReader(schemaString);
var schemaSource = Packages.javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource(schemaReader);
var schemaFactory = Packages.javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory.newInstance(Packages.javax.xml.XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
var schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(schemaSource);

var dbf = Packages.javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
dbf.setSchema(schema);
var db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
db.setErrorHandler(myErrorHandler);
var xmlReader2 = Packages.java.io.StringReader(xmlString);
var xmlInputSource = Packages.org.xml.sax.InputSource(xmlReader2);

xmlDoc = db.parse(xmlInputSource);
```

But I'm getting errors like this:

```
Error: cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'd.10'. No child element is expected at this point.
```

Where d.10 is the last child element of type "d".

I believe I'm improperly constructing the XSD - can anyone suggest an alternative approach?

Comment: I'm not sure why you are downvoted that this is not programming related, as you are clearly asking about a problem with your code, and you are showing what you did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your code is correct, so the problem is your input file. I took your XSD and amended it (but left the structure intact):

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"> 
    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>

                <xs:element name="a" type="aType"/>

                <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:element name="b" type="aType"/>
                    <xs:element name="c" type="aType"/>
                    <xs:element name="d" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="3" type="aType"/>
                </xs:sequence>

                <xs:element name="END" type="aType"/>

            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:simpleType name="aType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string" />
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

With the following XML, which follows the logic in your explanation, it validates:

```
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="xsd-choice-and%20occurrence.xsd">
    <a></a>
    <b></b>
    <c></c>
    <b></b>
    <c></c>
    <b></b>
    <c></c>
    <d></d>
    <d></d>
    <d></d>
    <b></b>
    <c></c>
    <d></d>
    <d></d>
    <d></d>
    <END></END>
</root>
```

The number `d` elements can be anywhere between 0 and 3.

Comment: Thanks Abel, what method/tool are you using to validate your XML? FYI, I didn't post my entire input XML because it is huge. But what's confusing me is in the input file which is generating that error, there are no "d" nodes at all. Yet, the error message is complaining about d.10 containing content when it shouldn't.

Comment: Got it! After trying your example XSD and XML successfully, I noticed that my large input XML was not properly ending some segments. In any case,  it's good to know that this sort of validation can be done with a Schema. Makes my job easier :)

Comment: @rmbri: [Xerces-J](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces-j/) internally, but from oXygen, because it's so easy there ;). If you get an error with the example I gave, the error is incorrect. But your original code was not what the same as what caused the error. If you want me to help with, make a [mcve].

Comment: @rmbri, we were posting at the same time. Glad you found it!